# Website security question with PHP? (Probably applies to ASP/Rails/etc.. too)

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Say, I have "index.htm" and "routines.php".

"index.htm" will call eventually call "routines.php" using JS (AJAX).

So, my question is, how can "routines.php" verify that the request came from the same local server and not outside? Is there a global variable I can check at PHP level or HTTP level?

**Edit 1:** Using AJAX

Comment: How does index.htm "calls" getdata()? Using Ajax?

Comment: I don't get it -- how would Ajax have access to that method (rather than requesting routines.php with some parameters).

Comment: yes, my mistake sorry, this AJAX thing is quite new to me. So my problem would be calling routines.php

Comment: If you pass the {name:'GetData'} from AJAX and send the request to routines.php, then in php you can call $name()  ?  Is that what you mean or am I on the wrong track?

Comment: Ok, then using Ozzy's reply you could avoid other websites from invoking your routines.php, but the solution for your own visitors depends on the actual usage. If every visitor can only call it once when each page is loaded then you need to generate a unique id each time index.html is rendered, store it in $_SESSION and include it as a parameter in the call to routines.php. But there are many more scenarios. So: in your question you still need to extend a bit on the limitations you want to enforce... And read the links Ionut G. Stan suggested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may forget about the Ajax part as it's not really part of the problem. You should read about Cross Site Request Forgeries (CSRF) and CSRF tokens. Some links:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery
- http://shiflett.org/articles/cross-site-request-forgeries

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question with another question: how would you invoke getdata() using a browser?

(So: no need to worry.)

Comment: Forgot to mention, using AJAX :P

Comment: still. when i open routines.php in my browser and the function is only defined in this file, nothing is gonna happen. and at the position where you call the function, you should have already verified whether the function can be called or not.

Comment: yep, opening routines.php from any browser won't do anything. But what if, someone make a similar index.htm, and it calls getdata() from my routines.php, the request is considered valid, no?

Comment: Even with Ajax you can only request routine.php, and not getdata() directly -- can you? Please show us some code then... But basically you cannot prevent someone from calling your Ajax methods. Even if you have some session and authentication in place, then still someone could first authenticate to get that session, and then invoke your Ajax calls. (We need more info for a detailed answer.)

Answer (score 1):

If the call is made in JavaScript (i.e., on the client), you really can't do anything to definitely prevent someone from simulating a request from index.htm, even if you check the `Referer` (sic) header.

If the request is made on the server side, you could use some kind of key.

You can of course generate a key on the client side too, but this security measure can be imitated by anyone to simulate a request from index.htm.

Answer (score 1):

you could use a session key:

index.htm

```
<?php

$_SESSION['safe_key'] = true;

?>
javascript code here
```

routines.php

```
<?php
if (!isset($_SESSION['safe_key'])) {
   die('from outside');
}

function getdata() { ... }
?>
```

Basically what happens is when index.htm is called a session safe key is created. Sessions are serverside only. In routines.php if the safe key does not exist, the code was not called from index.htm. If it does exist, run code.

Comment: ...still nothing prevents someone from sending the session cookie that is received by simply requesting index.html once.

Comment: you could use session_regenerate_id() to stop that happening :)

Comment: ...and then one would simply send that new cookie value (received when the Ajax call completes) along with the next request... :-) (Too bad we'll never know what Atlas was trying to avoid here.)

Comment: I ment call session_regenerate_id after every request to routines.php :P

Comment: Yes, but then still the Ajax response would include the new cookie?

Comment: Not quite. If the "hacker" gets ahold of the old session id, using it to request routines.php wont get it to send a new session id. Php will only send the new id once and that would be for the first and only request which would be done by index.php

Answer (score 0):

As others pointed out, it would be pretty difficult given your original specification. However, if you can change the `index.htm` to be `index.php` and have it output the same content as `index.htm`, you can also put in additional tokens for session management (e.g. Cookies - yes I know they are easy to spoof too :) and reject the call to `getdata()` if the tokens don't match.

Answer (score -2):

Use the HTTP_REFERER server variable:

```
echo $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']
```

With this you can know if the request comes from the server you want.

Comment: It's very easy to spoof the HTTP Referer header.

Comment: $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] is bad practice. you can't safely relay on this information.